# How to implement eloquent where has relationship with specific condition?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a case where i need to filter results by condition in 1-n relationship

so i have this 1-n relationship in User.php

```
public function permits()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Permit');
}
```

result i want to retrieve is users where **all permits are expired** (expiry on permits table = 0), because 1 user can own many permits, and the condition i need to met is from **all their permits they must be expired**

my current query is like this, this pulled several hundred wrong data because i didn't understand yet how to implement where all permits expiry = 0

```
$users = User::where('club_id',$this->id)->whereHas('permits',function($q){
        $q->where('expiry','<=','0');
    })->get();
```

current solution which is bad solution (longer time to execute), just so you guys clearer with what i want to achieve

```
foreach($users as $key => $user){
        foreach($user->permits as $permit){
            if($permit->expiry > 0){
                $users->forget($key); // unset from the users collection
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

any help would appreciated thank you!

Comment: What is the data type of `expiry` field in the database?

Comment: @akshaypjoshi tinyint

Comment: In closure function, try  `$q->where('expiry','<=',0);`

Comment: @akshaypjoshi well, it doesn't change anything because 1 user can own many permits, and there're permits that they own is expired, what i need is to filter from all permits they owned is not expired just like in the current bad solution i had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want users where **all permits are expired**

We can achieve this from `whereDoesntHave()` function.

```php
$users = User::where('club_id',$this->id)
             ->whereDoesntHave('permits', function($query){

                 // query for not expired.
                 // I believe the column expiry value is 0 when premit is not expired.
                 $query->where('expiry', 0);
             })
             ->get();
```

Technically what we did was get users where doesn't have non expired permits. Literally that means all permits are expired.